# How to delete an ApplicationUser in Asp.Net MVC 5 with Entity Framework (EF6)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm struggling with deleting an ApplicationUser in my application. I don't mind going with a hard delete, but that has given me a lot of challenges. The user can create posts in which other users can comment. If other users have commented on a user's post, the user can't be hard deleted since the delete is trying to cascade onto the post (which is blocked by the existing comments).

I'm also ok with a soft-delete approach, but this seems like a nightmare to deal with in a large application. I have found that I have to add `if (!user.IsDeleted){...}` around anything that mentions the user (comment and post author reference, login, register and almost everything in the Account/Manage controllers) and have to consider adding the check in all future additions to the code.

I have tried searching for established ways of handling user-deletes, but I can't seem to find any (other than quick articles like "how to add "IsDelete" property to your user, which does not go into nearly enough detail of the implications). So is there a proper way to handle user-deletes? It seems like the best way is to start getting my hands dirty with cascading but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: What do you want to show about the user when one of their posts are displayed?

Comment: "deleted" in place of the author. Post contents can still be displayed

Comment: So I guess they should actually be retrieved, but only display something else than their names.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to see the Soft-delete approach which it has been implemented on the ***ASP.NET Boilerplate***.It is **Free and Opensource**.

> Soft-delete filter is used to automatically filter (extract from
>   results) deleted entities while querying database. If an entity should
>   be soft-deleted, it must implement ISoftDelete interface which defines
>   only IsDeleted property.

Ex :

```
public class Person : Entity, ISoftDelete
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Link : [**ISoftDelete**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#DocSoftDelete)

[**Source Code on Github**](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate)

[**ASP.NET Boilerplate Documentation**](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents)